# Screen scraping javascript inserted dom elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, phantomjs, jsdom

I need to read a src attribute from an audio tag that's being inserted into the DOM by a third party javascript (so i can't modify it). It has to be done from the server side for multiple pages because the goal is to backup those sounds by reading their sources and saving them on the server.

What I tried so far is to use Node.js with jsdom/cheerio/phantom but none of them seem to do the trick because the call is being done before the element is inserted.

This is the phantom code:

```
var phantom = require( 'phantom' );
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page){
    page.open("https://mysite.cc/some-url", function(status) {
      console.log("opened site? ", status);
            page.injectJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' , function() {
                //jQuery Loaded.
                //Wait for a bit for AJAX content to load on the page. Here, we are waiting 5 seconds.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    return page.evaluate(function() {
                        var src = $("#audio_box").attr("src");
                        return {
                            src : src
                        };
                    }, function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        ph.exit();
                    });
                }, 50000);

            });
    });
    });
});
```

And this is the jsdom code:

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
  ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
  MutationEvents           : '2.0',
  QuerySelector            : false
};

request({ uri:'https://mysite.cc/some-url' }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Error when contacting google.com');
  }
  
  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
    ],
    done: function (err, window) {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        var audio = $('#audio_box');
        console.log(audio);
        }
    });
});
```

I read all that I could find about screen scraping but i couldn't find any clear answers about a server-side solution that waits for the sites scripts to fully load or that allows to listen to DOM changes or something similar.

I would be glad to have a solution to this even if it implies using another language, so any experience helps really!

> EDIT

I found a solution but its a very dirty one so I'll leave the question open in case someone has a better one.

What I'm doing now is that i'm getting the page using a curl request in PHP, injecting a jquery script at the end of the body tag and making it wait a few seconds, then recollect all the data the third party js injected, and ajax POST it out to another url in my server which captures the data and does the backup process.
For some reason the data was never inserted in a non-human interface (probably some user-agent check) so I had to ask the browser for some help in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the video element is inserted under a particular div element, say 'video-element',
you can listen to DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event as;

```
$('.video-element').on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function(){ ... })
```

or you can use the library called [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) to achieve the same.

What it does is, whenever there is a new dom element insertion happening under 'video-element', it fires 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument' event.

Comment: Thanks but how do I make this work server-side? I tried using event listeners but the node.js code waits until document ready, fires the callback and exits.